# Aptana has started crashing - possibly due to Python or Git

Tags: python, git, aptana

I've been happily using Aptana for a PHP project. As of yesterday evening, it's been crashing repeatedly and causing no end of grief!

I can pinpoint two events which may have caused this:

- Yesterday evening I seem to have hit a combination of keyboard keys which has resulted in 'Python not configured' appearing at the top of the App explorer window. I can't see anyway to turn Python off.
- I have also been trying to get Git to behave, and (away from Aptana) have been making changes to TortoiseGit and installing SmartGit.

Any ideas? (Specifically, can I turn off Python somehow to see if this helps?)

Comment: I would say this question is more suitable for SuperUser?

Comment: The crash log would also be very helpful. That should pinpoint the thread that's causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks - took me a while to find the Aptana log file (had found a temporary fix in the meantime, deleting the .metadata and .project folders and recreating it each time..). The error is "org.python.pydev.core.NotConfiguredInterpreterException". I don't seem to have anyway of uninstalling PyDev, and can't configure it because I don't have a Python interpreter (?). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to click on:
HELP -> About Aptana
then: Installation Details (button on the bottom left)
in the new window you can remove software, or revert some installation/configuration with with the "installation history" section.
Hope this help you